# Sync Random Numbers In UnityNetwork

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I want to assign random numbers to my objects that spawn when the server starts ,But every instance of the game makes its own random numbers and they don't sync together ,How can i fix that?

```
public class Health : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public Text PlanetHealth;
    public const int maxHealth = 100;

    [SyncVar(hook = "OnChangeHealth")]
    public int currentHealth = maxHealth;


    void Start()
    {
        if(this.gameObject.name == "GrayPlanet(Clone)")
        {
            currentHealth = Random.Range(0, 50);
            PlanetHealth.text = currentHealth.ToString();
        }
        else
            PlanetHealth.text = maxHealth.ToString();
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int amount)
    {
        if (!isServer)
        {
            return;
        }
        currentHealth -= amount;
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            currentHealth = 55;
        }
    }
    void OnChangeHealth(int currentHealth)
    {
        PlanetHealth.text = currentHealth.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help https://answers.unity.com/questions/1356262/networking-unity-i-need-to-pass-a-simple-variable.html

Answer (score 2):

Just add this at the beginning of your `Start()` method:

```
if (!isServer)
{
    return;
}
```

You should do the random generation only in the server side. After that, `SyncVar` will do the job of keeping the instances up to date.

Comment: it doesn't work now all the planet at the client side  are at 0

Comment: You should add `currentHealth = maxHealth` after the `else` in the `Start` method.